# Stop all application operation before ServiceHost closes or stops

Tags: c#, wcf, msmq, servicehost

I have a class that inherits from the `ServiceBase` class. On the `OnStop` method, I stop the `ServiceHost`:

```
protected override void OnStop()
{
    if (this.serviceHost != null)
    {
         this.serviceHost.Close();
    }
}
```

The thing is, I want to let the application finish processing messages from the queue before the service stops (running in `ConcurrencyMode.Multiple, InstanceContextMode.Single` with MSMQ and WCF). Is there a way to do this? I tried to keep restarting the service while the queue is running, and sometimes I lose data (maybe some messages were running in the middle of the operation when it stopped)

Comment: That doesn't look right. I'd have expected you to call the stop method for each service being hosted. In the service you implement stop, and it sets an internal property that makes it wind up processing then exits it main loop.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to [RequestAdditionalTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicebase.requestadditionaltime%28v=vs.110%29.aspx%5D)